# Forms of Geometric Series

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

I came across three forms of geometric series and all make sense with the exception of one: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n+1}$

If the first term of the geometric series has to be a, how does n start at 1 and r is to the power of n+1?

Comment: You can rescue the formality that worries you by thinking of this as a geometric series with first term $ar$ and ration $r$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n+1}$ is a geometric series with first term $ar^2$ and common ratio $r.$ Instead of using specific formulas to work with them, especially infinite geometric series, it's much simpler to think in terms of "first term" and "common ratio".

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. The first term of a geometric series can be called anything you want. The point is that ratios of successive terms are the same constant. So here the first term is $ar^2$, the ratio is $r$, and if $|r| < 1$, then the sum is $\frac{ar^2}{1-r}$.